# Add-on Dev: Balance columns in layout?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have a panel with two long columns, where each one contains a few vertical blocks (sub-layouts) of UI elements. Any of the blocks (of elements) can be missing, so I'm using `column_flow()` to try to balance left and right sides.

However, some blocks are vertically longer than others. Since any of the blocks may be skipped/hidden, I can't visually control the order they get drawn. So I'm worried the left side may end up with all of the tall blocks, while the right side ends up with all of the short blocks, which would waste a lot of space.

That is - unless `column_flow()` is smarter than I think it is. Does it deal with the number of elements, or the pixel sizes of them? If it only deals with the number of them, is there any way to help balance the layout based on the space taken up? Or if anyone just knows something that might help, I appreciate it.

Also, if anyone is aware of any documentation about these functions, I would really like to see it. The official 2.8 docs do not elaborate much at all.

Comment: You can find the code for this in `interface_layout.c` in the function `static void ui_litem_estimate_column_flow(uiLayout *litem)`. I haven't taken a closer look at the code, but that function would be the definitive answer as to how it works (at the time of writing). https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/interface/interface_layout.c

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what type of units they are measuring. But from what I can gather, it looks like they are counting heights and switching to the next column when one is larger than some total. I'm hoping this will do exactly what I want. I will come back and update once I've seen enough to know for sure. Thanks for finding that section.